# Google API Client users().get(userKey='name@domain.com') returns Not Authorized to access this resource/api

Tags: python, google-admin-sdk, google-api-python-client, http-error

I'm trying to see if an email account with `name@domain.com` already exists but I keep getting this error:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/name%domain.comL?alt=json returned "Not Authorized to access this resource/api">
```

Although I successfully use the users().insert() method from my code with the same credentials. 
I've tried the ["Try it"](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get#try-it) webpage for this exact request and noticed two things.

1. It worked with the same scopes I'm using (listed below)
2. The GET URL they are providing is `https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/name%40domain.com?key={YOUR_API_KEY}`
   and not `https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/name%domain.comL?alt=json`. I'm just guessing this is just using the OAuth generated key right in the URL.

I'm writing in Python and use google api for python https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/tree/master/googleapiclient.

The scopes that I'm using:

```
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
```

Comment: Have you enabled the Admin SDK in Developer Console, API Keys and Authorized API access (OAuth 2.0)?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned, `users().insert(...)` works just fine.

Comment: is it resolved?